# My iMac crashes when trying to open Terminal, when trying to Launch App Store, and also when trying to run Flash

Tags: macos, mac

Here is the crash log when I try and run Terminal. All of these problems started happening at the same time, so I am guessing they are related.

I had also purchased Lion from the App Store, but the download is stalled halfway from a while ago and will not resume.

These problems also occur across all of my user accounts.

I am running OSX 10.6.8

```
Process:         Terminal [4752]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
Identifier:      com.apple.Terminal
Version:         2.1.2 (273.1)
Build Info:      Terminal-2730100~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [2663]

Date/Time:       2011-12-26 12:41:08.253 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          487948 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           146
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1556529 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   10
Anonymous UUID:                      1CFCDEC3-E479-4E32-9E0B-6B5951A13600

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001c
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0x000000000000001c 0 + 28
1   libTrueTypeScaler.dylib         0x00007fff82e2c7ff sbit_GetBitMapData(fsg_SplineKey*, scalerGlyph const*, scalerBitmap*, void*, unsigned char, int) + 1477
2   libTrueTypeScaler.dylib         0x00007fff82e264bc RenderBitmap(fsg_SplineKey*, memoryContext*, scalerGlyph const*, scalerBitmap*, int) + 1686
3   libTrueTypeScaler.dylib         0x00007fff82e257ac TTRenderGlyphs + 698
4   libFontParser.dylib             0x00007fff858e4d5a TConcreteFontScaler::CopyGlyphBitmap(unsigned short, unsigned int, CGRect*, unsigned long*) const + 248
5   libFontParser.dylib             0x00007fff858e4bf9 FPFontCopyGlyphBitmap + 214
6   libCGXType.A.dylib              0x00007fff838a619b create_glyph_bitmap + 79
7   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff85a4864f CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap + 93
8   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff85a484e5 create_missing_bitmaps + 294
9   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff859f64cf CGGlyphLockLockGlyphBitmaps + 399
10  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff88b15ebd ripc_RenderGlyphs + 261
11  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff88b1589b ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1497
12  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff859f4967 draw_glyphs + 1527
13  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff859f426e CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances + 538
14  com.apple.Terminal              0x0000000100052edf 0x100000000 + 339679
15  com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010001892e 0x100000000 + 100654
16  com.apple.Terminal              0x0000000100017f5f 0x100000000 + 98143
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af8cc5 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3390
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af7938 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1325
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af7ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af7ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af7ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af7ca2 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2199
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af600a -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 767
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af6ed6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4555
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af5b2c -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 254
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83af23de -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83a6bc0e -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83a66aba _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 678
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81a19b37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 519
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff819f5464 __CFRunLoopRun + 468
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff819f4dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874df7ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874df5f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874df4ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83a3beb2 _DPSNextEvent + 708
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83a3b801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83a0168f -[NSApplication run] + 395
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff839fa3b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
39  com.apple.Terminal              0x0000000100001d30 0x100000000 + 7472

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e2c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e4add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e47b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e42de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e2c0a kevent + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x00000001000024f1 0x100000000 + 9457
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88861204 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102fd6 _pthread_start + 331
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810e3aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff810d4466 read + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010000b374 0x100000000 + 45940
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88861204 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102fd6 _pthread_start + 331
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8110d932 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010000cfb3 0x100000000 + 53171
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88861204 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102fd6 _pthread_start + 331
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81102e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000010000  rbx: 0x00007fff5fbf9200  rcx: 0x0000000000000006  rdx: 0x0000000000010000
  rdi: 0x00007fff5fbf9200  rsi: 0x0000000103845e5c  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbf9260  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbf9198
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fff5fbf9560  r10: 0x0000000103845e5c  r11: 0x00007fff5fbf92f0
  r12: 0x0000000000000018  r13: 0x00007fff5fbf9510  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000006
  rip: 0x000000000000001c  rfl: 0x0000000000010212  cr2: 0x000000000000001c

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100094ff7  com.apple.Terminal 2.1.2 (273.1) <D9179843-A8BE-5A77-F845-8CE81BA51F71> /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
       0x1007ac000 -        0x1007b0ff7  libFontRegistryUI.dylib ??? (???) <763B8E8F-8602-2096-7CC8-CEE1F4248028> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Resources/libFontRegistryUI.dylib
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <472D950D-70F8-B810-A959-9184C2AA6C74> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80003000 -     0x7fff80056ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff80193000 -     0x7fff801a1ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff801a2000 -     0x7fff801b4fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff80210000 -     0x7fff802c5fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <FFC46EE0-3544-A459-2AB9-94778A75E3D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff802c6000 -     0x7fff802e9fff  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff80344000 -     0x7fff80381ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <4C3293E2-851B-55CE-3BE3-29C425DD5DFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff803c4000 -     0x7fff8047aff7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8047b000 -     0x7fff804f9ff7  com.apple.CoreText 151.10 (???) <54961997-55D8-DC0F-2634-674E452D5A8E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff806c9000 -     0x7fff806d6fe7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <1C35FA50-9C70-48DC-9E8D-2054F7A266B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff806d7000 -     0x7fff80756fe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff80850000 -     0x7fff80c93fef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff80c94000 -     0x7fff80cbbff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <46A413EA-4FD1-A050-2EF0-6279F3EAD581> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff80dd6000 -     0x7fff80e86fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff80f88000 -     0x7fff80f8eff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff80f8f000 -     0x7fff80f90ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <74800EE8-C14C-18C9-C208-20BBDB982D40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff80f91000 -     0x7fff80fb6ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff81047000 -     0x7fff81088fef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff81097000 -     0x7fff810c8fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <7F102A07-E4FB-9F52-B2F6-4E2D2383CA13> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff810c9000 -     0x7fff8128afef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff81290000 -     0x7fff81294ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff8154c000 -     0x7fff81595fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <1C050088-4AB2-2BC2-62E6-C969F925A945> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff815d2000 -     0x7fff815d9fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4200CFB0-DBA1-62B8-7C7C-91446D89551F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff8164d000 -     0x7fff8176cfe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff817ae000 -     0x7fff817e9fff  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff817ea000 -     0x7fff819a8ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4 (3.0.4) <0A4F51A1-4502-767B-8A4E-F14C6214EF88> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff819a9000 -     0x7fff81b20fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.5 (550.43) <31A1C118-AD96-0A11-8BDF-BD55B9940EDC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff81b21000 -     0x7fff81b6dfff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff81d46000 -     0x7fff81d95fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <1E2593D1-A7F6-84C6-DF8F-0B46AE445926> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff82021000 -     0x7fff82022ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <53299948-2554-0F8F-7501-04B34E49F6CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff82023000 -     0x7fff8204eff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <8AB4CA9E-435A-33DA-7041-904BA7FA11D5> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff822c9000 -     0x7fff822d8fef  com.apple.opengl 1.6.13 (1.6.13) <516098B3-4517-8A55-64BB-195CDAA5334D> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff822db000 -     0x7fff822e1ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <04EDCEDE-E36F-15F8-DC67-E61E149D2C9A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff822e2000 -     0x7fff823a3fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.6 (4.6.6) <BB2C5813-C61D-3CBA-A8F7-0E59E46EBEE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff823a4000 -     0x7fff8240efe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <75A8D840-4ACE-6560-0889-2AFB6BE08E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8240f000 -     0x7fff82c19fe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff82c1a000 -     0x7fff82c2bff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FB5EE53A-0534-0FFA-B2ED-486609433717> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff82c2c000 -     0x7fff82d00fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <C83E2BA1-1818-B3E8-5334-860AD21D1C80> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff82d01000 -     0x7fff82d01ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <DA9BFF01-40DF-EBD5-ABB7-787DAF2D77CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff82d02000 -     0x7fff82d05ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <38935851-09E4-DDAB-DB1D-30ADC39F7ED0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff82d06000 -     0x7fff82d2efff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff82d2f000 -     0x7fff82d5ffef  com.apple.shortcut 1.1 (1.1) <A99C9D8E-290B-B1E4-FEA5-CC5F2FB9C18D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Shortcut.framework/Versions/A/Shortcut
    0x7fff82e1e000 -     0x7fff82e51ff7  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib ??? (???) <69D4A213-45D2-196D-7FF8-B52A31DFD329> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
    0x7fff82efb000 -     0x7fff82f10ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <DC999B32-BF41-94C8-0583-27D9AB463E8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff82f11000 -     0x7fff82f1cff7  com.apple.HelpData 2.0.5 (34.1.1) <24DC6CD3-02B7-9332-FF6D-F0C545857B55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HelpData.framework/Versions/A/HelpData
    0x7fff82f1d000 -     0x7fff82f22fff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <201B8077-B5CC-11AA-E1B0-1D057ABE416A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff82f42000 -     0x7fff82f59fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <79AB2131-2A6C-F351-38A9-ED58B25534FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff82f5a000 -     0x7fff82f5ffff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <1D0D3531-9561-632C-D620-1A8652BEF5BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff82f60000 -     0x7fff82f80ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.11) <AD76C757-6701-BDB5-631E-1CB77D669586> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff82f81000 -     0x7fff83066fef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff83362000 -     0x7fff83378fe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff8338f000 -     0x7fff833aaff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <FD46A0FE-AC79-3EF7-AB4F-396D376DDE71> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff833ab000 -     0x7fff83569fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <4274FC73-A257-3A56-4293-5968F3428854> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8356a000 -     0x7fff8356fff7  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <4D84803B-BD06-D80E-15AE-EFBE43F93605> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff83854000 -     0x7fff838a3ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <01B370FB-D524-F660-3826-E85B7F0D85CD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
    0x7fff838a4000 -     0x7fff838a8ff7  libCGXType.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <DB710299-B4D9-3714-66F7-5D2964DE585B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
    0x7fff838a9000 -     0x7fff838e8fef  libncurses.5.4.dylib 5.4.0 (compatibility 5.4.0) <E1F34D53-3D62-78C0-CAD8-8AD22C110A9E> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff8397c000 -     0x7fff8397ffff  com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <BD1B0A22-1CB8-263E-FF85-5BBFDE3660B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff83980000 -     0x7fff83994ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff83995000 -     0x7fff83995ff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <68B0BE46-6E24-C96F-B341-054CF9E8F3B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff839f8000 -     0x7fff843f2ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff843f3000 -     0x7fff84727fef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff84728000 -     0x7fff84728ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <08D3D45D-908B-B86A-00BA-0F978D2702A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff84d48000 -     0x7fff84d48ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <2BB7D669-4B40-6A52-ADBD-DA4DB3BC0B1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff84d6c000 -     0x7fff84dfcfff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff84dfd000 -     0x7fff84e03ff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff8578a000 -     0x7fff858bffff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <E5D7DBDB-6DDF-E6F9-C71C-86F4520EE5A3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff858cb000 -     0x7fff8598cfff  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <A00BB0A7-E46C-1D07-1391-194745566C7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff859c8000 -     0x7fff860c4ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff860e5000 -     0x7fff860e6fff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff860e7000 -     0x7fff860e7ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <3F2751FE-AAB2-F30C-0284-5A78E6FEF1CC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff861de000 -     0x7fff86218fff  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <539EBFDD-96D6-FB07-B128-40232C408757> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff86320000 -     0x7fff86323ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <E03D7C81-A3DA-D44A-A88A-DDBB98AF910B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff8635e000 -     0x7fff8635eff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8635f000 -     0x7fff86361fff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <A9DB4D5D-4072-971B-DEF6-DDE645F415EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff863aa000 -     0x7fff863b5ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <F0DDF27E-DB55-07CE-E548-C62095BE8167> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff86594000 -     0x7fff86594ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff8660f000 -     0x7fff8669bfef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <D844BB57-386A-0A43-249E-9BE035C2AB53> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff8737b000 -     0x7fff87394fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff87395000 -     0x7fff87472fff  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff874b1000 -     0x7fff877affff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff877b0000 -     0x7fff8786dfff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <BBB8888E-18DE-5D09-3C3A-F4C029EC7886> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff87875000 -     0x7fff87884fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff87885000 -     0x7fff878ccff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <D7645B59-0431-6283-7322-957D944DAB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff878cd000 -     0x7fff87c6afe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff87c6b000 -     0x7fff87c7ffff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff87c80000 -     0x7fff87ccaff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <2EF19055-D7AE-4D77-E589-7B71B0BC1E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff87ccb000 -     0x7fff87d6bfff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices


Model: iMac11,3, BootROM IM112.0057.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.93 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.59f2
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5750, ATI Radeon HD 5750, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 2.1.14.6
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 931.51 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256B, 233.76 GB
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Hub, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x1008, 0xfa140000 / 5
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2504, 0xfd130000 / 6
USB Device: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc051, 0xfd133000 / 8
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2503, 0xfd131000 / 7
USB Device: Flash Card Reader, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2228, 0xfd131100 / 9
USB Device: Razer Marauder, 0x1532, 0x001a, 0xfd140000 / 5
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8502, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Did you install any fonts recently?

Comment: Someone emailed me a font, but I don't think I installed it, and when I checked Font Book and the fonts folder, it wasn't there. I also tried moving all of my font to the desktop, but that didn't seem to help. I also checked Font Book for duplicate fonts and some fonts someone warned about on a forum, but found nothing.

Comment: Formatting fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a hardware error, try to run memory and disk tests.